# Shooting direction isnt the same between line renderer and bullet

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm implementing my first Third person game. In this game I want to shoot at the direction of the mouse. Therefore I cast a ray from the camera to the ground. To make the shooting better I draw a line from the player to the current mouse position (see screenshot).

If the player presses the fire button, a bullet should spawn and shoot in the direction of the line renderer.

Unfortunally the bullet is not flying to the direction of the mouse and I'm not sure why?

Both scripts: Line renderer and bullet spawn and shoot are on the same gameobject.

**Current Code**

Line Renderer:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(200, 200, 0);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) 
    {


        linePointing = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z); // really unnecessary but I want the line Pointing as my hit point

        linePointing.y = gameObject.transform.position.y;
        Vector3 localCord = gameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(linePointing);



        float angle = Mathf.Atan(localCord.x / localCord.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        //This is just so the player cant shoot in every direction
        if (Mathf.Abs(angle) < 80 && localCord.z > 0)
        {
            m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, localCord);
            m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(2, localCord * 100);
        }


    }

}
```

**Bullet spawn (also in update)**

```
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
    bullet.transform.parent = gameObject.transform.parent;

    Physics.IgnoreCollision(bullet.GetComponent<Collider>(), bulletSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>());

    bullet.transform.position = bulletSpawn.position;

    Vector3 rotation = bullet.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rotation.z);
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(getShootingDirection().normalized * bulletSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);

    //Change parent, so the player movement doesnt affect the bullet
    bullet.transform.parent = null;
```

**Get shooting direction-Method**
This method is same as the line renderer ones but I want to have it separate

```
 private Vector3 getShootingDirection()
{
    Vector3 linePointing = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 localCord = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(200, 200, 0);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
    {
        linePointing = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z)
        {
            y = hit.point.y + 0.5f
        };

        localCord = gameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(linePointing);


    }
    return localCord;

}
```

Picture of line renderer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RigidbodyAddforce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) adds a force in world coordinates, and I think you are adding the force in local coordinates. You can check that out.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understood your answer, because I dont understand why I m adding force localy. In my point of view I want the direction to be from the player because otherwise the bullet direction wont be to the point I clicked thats why I calculate the local coordinates of the force. Is that wrong ?

Comment: InverseTransformPoint switches a position from world space to local space. And in your `getShootingDirection()` you do  `localCord = gameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(linePointing);` which I do not quite understand really. I did not dig much in your code, but according to my understandind the force direction should be `(hit.point - bulletSpawn.position).normalized`, a direction in the world space, as the RigidbodyAddforce demands in its argument a force vector in world coordinates. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes this makes sense and it worked. Thanks. I thought that ameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(linePointing) is doing something like this but unfortunally it didnt.